# Can't resize image to 100% in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JavaScript slider that I want to be 100% of the width.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mhblindsshow">
  <style type="text/css"> #mhblindsshow img { display:none; } </style>                  
  <a href="blogpost.php"><img src="images/main/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="blogpost.php"><img src="images/main/2.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.mhSlideshow {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;    
}

.mhSlideshow img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  display:none;
}
```

and here is the javacript that controls the width.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mhblindsshow").mhslideshow({
        width: $(window).width(), height: 500,
        scaleMode: 'scaleToFill',
        firstSlide: 0,
        randomPlay: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        showShadow: false,
        loopForever: true, loop: 0,
        showBorder: false, borderSize: 6, borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        effectMode: 'blind', interval: 2500, effectSpeed: 1000,
        totalSlices: 5, sliceInterval: 50,
        showCaption: false,
        textCSS: '.title {
            font-size:12px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family:Arial;
            color:#ffffff;
            line-height:200%;
            }
            .alt {
            font-size:12px;
            font-family:Arial;
            color:#ffffff;
            }',
        captionPosition: 'bottom', captionBarColor: '#333333', captionBarOpacity: 0.8, 
        captionBarPadding: 8, captionAlign: 'center',
        showNavArrows: true, autoHideNavArrows: false,
        showNavDots: true, navDotsBottom: 6,
        navDotsAlign: 'right', navDotsLeftRightMargin: 16,
        effect: 'fade',
        jsFolder: 'js'
     });
 });
```

If my image is larger/smaller then the window, the image doesn't fit to 100%.
I would want the image width to always be 100% and the height should be flexible based on image ratio.

I tried adding width:100% in the CSS, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please don't paste minified code here.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue? That would help in finding a solution.

Comment: When width and height are set to 100% that are becoming 100% of the width and height of the parent container. It doesn't look like your parent element has a set width and height. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").css("height","100%");
$("img").css("width","100%");
```

this code require jquery library
and U should use class or id at html so will be img.class or img#id

Comment: it's not working... if I put :  `width: $("img").css("width","100%");,
        height: $("img").css("height","100%");,`  in my js... the image doesn't display at all...

Comment: do U include jquery library ?